# How to hide a tab bar view controller with another view controller over it?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In Periscope Live Broadcast app, when you click on WORLD tab bar and then tap on "List" and you tap to watch a live stream, the Live stream view controller will pop up from the bottom covering the entire tab bar view controller with the tab bar completely hidden.

(I'm currently using Tab Bar Controller and Navigation Controller and I can't get it done)

How is this done?

Comment: Are you using storyboard ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Storyboard and coding in Obj-C

Answer (score 0):

You can call your "modal" view controller programmatically:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard"; 
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER` is the name you set in your storyboard. You can assign in the identity inspector of your storyboard.

This view will cover your screen as a modal

Comment: Thanks but, I just figured it out myself. Your code didn't work for what I was looking to establish.